# A Real Matrix, its Kernel and Image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

This is an old exam problem: For an $m \times n$ real matrix $A$, define $\ker A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax=0 \}$ and $\operatorname{Im} A = \{Ax \mid x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$. Show that for all $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, there is $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\|Ax - b \| \leq \|Ay - b\|$. Here, $\|z\| = \sqrt{z^Tz}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

So, I'm thinking there is a way to work with $\|Ay -b\|$i.e. expanding it out and getting something that will help you prove this inequality. Although I have tried this and have seemingly gotten nowhere. The choice of $x$ is perplexing to me though, but perhaps I'm just not seeing something obvious. Any advice?

Comment: Do you have a statement in your textbook about convex sets?

Comment: Alternatively, do you know about the projection onto a subspace?

Answer (score 0):

I that think the key to answering this question is to recognize that Im(A) is a subspace of `ℝ^m`.

It means that for a given `b ∈ ℝ^m`, there exists a point of Im(A) closest to b; namely, the orthogonal projection of b onto Im(A). We can write this projection as *Ax*, for some `x ∈ ℝ^n`, by the definition of Im(A). Thus, we have the result that for any other point *Ay* ∈ Im(A), `∥Ax−b∥ ≤ ∥Ay−b∥`.